# C++ Code::blocks difficulty compiling

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml, mingw-w64

I am quite new to programming, and was working on a project at school which I hoped to take home and complete, and so I copied all the files (including that of code::blocks) thinking that I would simply be able to get it up and running quickly! However when I open the file and attempt to run the program I get a list of errors such as:

> undefined reference to '_Unwind_SjLj_Register'
>
> undefined reference to '_Unwind_SjLj_Resume'
>
> undefined reference to '__gxx_personality_sj0'
>
> undefined reference to '_Unwind_SjLj_Unregister'

and many more..

I assume this problem is likely caused by missing files since the computer I copied it from likely had a different directory. Or could it be because I am on a 64 bit version of windows 7, compared to the 32 bit version I was working on? (I really don't know just trying to think of some potential ideas).

Does anyone know of a solution? Should I simply uninstall and attempt to reinstall with minGW and SFML myself? Or is there a way to get around this without having to uninstall.

Thanks

Comment: You should install the tools you need and only copy the files of the project.

Comment: Make sure you're linking with `g++` not `gcc`, otherwise it won't link with the C++ runtime library.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Pretty certain I am linked with g++ (or atleast, the box marked as "have g++ follow the C++11 ISO..." is ticked), but if thats not it, then you may be right!

Comment: Be sure you delete all the object files and other intermediate files from the build tree.  This is usually called "clean" in a build environment.  Compiled objects may have compatibility issues across compilers and systems, but your source code should be completely portable, if you did it right.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler seem to be incompatible. If you've installed Qt with MinGW bundled together, you'll most likely have gotten [MinGW 4.8.0 DW2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingwbuilds/files/host-windows/releases/4.8.0/32-bit/threads-posix/dwarf/) installed - it's the compiler for which a [Qt package](http://qt-project.org/downloads) exists. On the other hand, if you've used the compiler that shipped with [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26) you've most likely used the [TDM 4.7.1 SJLJ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tdm-gcc/files/TDM-GCC%20Installer/Previous/1.1006.0/) compiler.

If you now try to use the same SFML libs or object files with from one compiler with another compiler, it won't work. Instead you'll have to option to either use the same compiler on both systems or compile everything freshly for both compilers.

Comment: I just re-installed my codeblocks, minGW and SFML following this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZqjNOd1UYtE however I have still gotten the same error messages.

Comment: That video is already outdated. The official MinGW version changed to GCC 4.8.x as well just a few weeks ago, thus the precompiled package from the SFML download website won't work with your compiler. The best solution is to recompile everything with the same compiler. See the official [SFML CMake tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/compile-with-cmake.php).

Comment: Thanks! Followed those instructions and it seems to be working now!

Comment: I'm glad it works now! Feel free to mark this question as solved.